# display images with same key in PHP?

Tags: php

I'm trying to display all the images with the same key from a folder.

the images are stored like so:

```
34526Image1.jpg
34526Image2.jpg
34526Image3.jpg
34526Image4.jpg
etc etc....
```

so the key is the first part of the image name  (the random numbers) which in this case is **34526**.

I've tried to use `glob()` function in PHP but I only get the first image which is `34526Image1.jpg`.

my `glob()` code is this:

```
<?php
        foreach(glob('../my-images/') as $image) 
        $i = 1;
    {   

            $pic_list .= '<a id="example1" href="'.$image.''.$randKey.'Image'.$i++.'.jpg"><img alt="example1" src="../my-images/'.$randKey.'Image'.$i++.'.jpg" /></a>'; 
    }


 echo $pic_list ; 

 ?>
```

could someone please advise on this?

Comment: You're giving all of the pictures the same `id`. That needs to be fixed, `id`'s cannot be duplicated in a page without some funky results. You're also incrementing your `$i` early, that may give you some issues like skipping the number 1.

Comment: @JayBlanchard, your comment is more of a HTML point out but this question is PHP related.

Comment: Right @William, but if you still need to do it properly. That is why I made it a comment, because it doesn't answer your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your call to `glob` contains no pattern. You can use wildcards for no or many characters with `*`, or for single characters using `?`. Also ranges like for example `[0-9]` are possible. In your case you want everything that starts with a random number, determinted by `$randKey`, followed by the word `Image`, a counter value and `.jpg`. So all you have to do is to use a wildcard for the counter value like in your example `34526Image*.jpg`.
This results in the following code

```
<?php
    $pic_list = '';
    $id = 0;
    foreach(glob('../my-images/'.$randKey.'Image*.jpg') as $image) {   
        $pic_list .= '<a id="example'.++$id.'" href="'.$image.'"><img alt="example'.$id.'" src="'.$image.'" /></a>'; 
    }
    echo $pic_list; 
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

you have error in your foreach statement, for each file in folder you execute only 1 code line `$i = 1;`, everything after `;` is executed only one time, after all iterations of foreach

you need to use proper foreach:

```
$files = glob('../my-images/'); // need to define proper mask here to get only files with $randKey

$i = 1;
foreach($files as $image) 
{   
    $pic_list .= '<a id="example1" href="'.$image.''.$randKey.'Image'.$i.'.jpg">';
    $pic_list .= '<img alt="example1" src="../my-images/'.$randKey.'Image'.$i.'.jpg" />';
    $pic_list .= '</a>';
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: What's improper about the OP's `foreach()`?

Comment: @JayBlanchard: The position of the line `$i = 1;` and the `{`.  He's looping the line `$i = 1;` over and over and then running a block of code that appends one element to `$pic_list`.

Comment: @JayBlanchard position of `$i=1` and double `$i++` in output string

Comment: Then please explain that in your answer so the OP will learn rather than have to try to figure out the difference.

Comment: this will produce the exact same result as my own code.

Comment: @william no, this will produce totally different output

Comment: @Lashane, I have checked it and it produces an identical result.

Comment: @william then you have another error, I suppose you're using wrong path in glob

Comment: No, the path is correct because as I said in my question, I always get the first image but not the rest of them which are in the same folder/directory.

Comment: @william try to output `print_r(glob('../my-images/'));` and you will see

Comment: that would give me Array
(
    [0] => ../my-images/
)